# Global cors not working in spring security 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

When I tested my app locally using postman it was very confusing, I was able to access any /public path api, what am I doing wrong, but I found that my code really didn't do anything to protect the cors,
I following this official guild:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title

```
    public static final String[] URL_WHITELIST = new String[]{
            "/static/**",
            "/api/public/**"
    };
    public static final String[] URL_ANONYMOUS = new String[]{
            "/api/auth/sign-in",
    };

    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            //...
                .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(URL_ANONYMOUS).anonymous()
                .requestMatchers(URL_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(https://example.com,https://admin.example.com));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: CORS is _not_ meant to strengthen security.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that the api can only be accessed from the front-end application?

Comment: No. But you should put authentication/authorisation in place, if the API isn't meant to be public.

Comment: Try to remove the securityMatcher, for me it start to work when I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
      }
    };
  }
```

Also update your `SecurityFilterChain`. Don't disable cors. :

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests.......
```

Comment: Still not working when i test using postman locally.
I guess this is due to the fact that I have set permitAll. But the problem is that I don't know how to juggle public access and same source.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your problem. If you send request from postman you will never get cors error. CORS is depended to your browser and backend.

Comment: I'm concerned that when putting the code on the server, the api with the /public path seems to be a security risk if someone uses postman to scrape it. I'm new to this and I don't know how to describe exactly what I need, but I just want my front-end pages to access this interface.

Comment: Sorry but i think its impossible. If frontend can request to backend, you can send request from postman/curl or from anything else. But maybe you can implement ratelimiter to block too many requests

Comment: Is there any way to securely set up public requests? For example, is it possible to set a unique identity for each user who visits the site and use that as authentication for the request? This is just my idea, I don't know if this fits the usual usage scenario.

Comment: just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981202/how-to-block-access-to-my-api-from-postman-other-apis-etc-spring-boot

Comment: I reviewed link that you have provided. I agree to him. You can mimic any request, even if you add unique identifier to your request. For example open network from chrome dev tools/F12 and right click to any request. You will able to copy request as CURL. You will get all params. headers etc.

Comment: Is there any way or library to add authentication to a public api to prevent development tools from making calls? I guess this is a relatively accurate description of my problem

Comment: I seem to have sorted out the logic. I could try setting up an authentication request on the front end that just enters the page, sets USER permissions and returns jwt. Then change premitAll to hasRole("USER") and every access from the front end should carry it for authentication.